Serilog.Sinks.Email Send to pickup directory
Is it possible for serilog to send emails to pickup directory? I don't actually want to send emails right now it's just a POC.
Thank you

Yes, it is possible for serilog to send emails to pickup directory for POC purpose. For production environment, I would recommend to use Serilog.Sinks.Email with SMTP based configuration.
I am providing an example with console application. You can use same code for pretty much any type of asp.net core based application. You can find the full example code on my GitHub repo at here.
 
You need to install the Serilog.Sinks.EmailPickup NuGet package first. Here is the link to the package. For more, detail information on the package use
After that you can use it something like below in Program.cs while configuring Serilog logger. You need to include these using statements using Serilog; and using Serilog.Sinks.EmailPickup;.
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()        
            .WriteTo.EmailPickup(
                fromEmail: "doNotReply@domain.com",
                toEmail: "ConsoleApp.Support@domain.com",
                pickupDirectory: @"c:\logs\emailpickup",
                subject: "There is something wrong with consoleapp",
                fileExtension: ".eml",
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error)
           .CreateLogger();

This will drop an email to the mentioned path in pickupDirectory with the logging information.

The email looks like below.

